# Is there an increasing function on $[a, b]$ which is differentiable, but not absolutely continuous？

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there an increasing function on
$[a, b]$ which is differentiable,
but not absolutely continuous？

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An elementary non-existence proof may be of interest.

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ an increasing, continuous, and not absolutely continuous function: I claim there exists a point $c\in[a,b]$ where the Dini derivative $D^*f(c):=\limsup_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$  is infinite. For the proof, we may assume w.l.o.g. that $f$ is *strictly* increasing (we may just consider $x+f(x)$).

By definition, since $f$ is not absolutely continuous, there exists a sequence of sets $J_n\subset [a,b]$ such that  each $J_n$ is a finite union of intervals, $|J_n|\to0$, and $|f(J_n)|$ is bounded away from $0$.

Let $J^*_n\subset J_n$ be the union of all components $I$ of $J_n$ such that $|f(I)|\ge\frac12\frac {|f(J_n)|}{|J_n|}|I|$. Clearly, $|f(J_n\setminus J_n^*)|\le\frac {|f(J_n)|}2$, so the sets $f(J_n^*)$
have  length $|f( J_n^*)|\ge\frac {|f(J_n)|}2$ bounded away from $0$  too. This implies ($\dagger$) that some $p \in f([a,b])$ belongs to infinitely many $f( J_n^*)$. Therefore $c:=f^{-1}(p)$ belongs to infinitely many $J_n^*$; for  these indices, let $[\alpha_n,\beta_n]$ be the component of $c$ in $J_n$. So by construction  both $\beta_n$ and $\alpha_n$ converge to $c$ along a subsequence; and w.r.to this subsequence, $\max\big\{\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(c)}{\beta_n-c},\frac{f(c)-f(\alpha_n)}{c-\alpha_n}\big\}\ge\frac{f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}=\frac{|f(I_n)|}{|I_n|}\to+\infty$, proving that $D^*f(c)=+\infty$.

($\dagger$) It's the well-known argument from measure theory: For a finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$, if for $n\in\mathbb N$ one has $Y_n\in\mathcal{S}$ and $\mu(Y_n)\ge \lambda$, then $\overline{Y}:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}Y_n:=\cap_{k\in\mathbb N}\cup_{n\ge k}Y_n$ also has  $\mu(\overline{Y})\ge \lambda$. Here $Y_n:=f( J_n^*)$.

Comment: Note that the above argument proves that the image of the set $\{D^*f=+\infty\}$ has in fact positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: (In case that $\alpha_n=c$ or $\beta_n=c$, we agree for notation sake that $0/0$ is to be removed from the argument of the max)

Comment: @LSpice ok - my apologies for too many edits :)

Answer (score 14):

Such a function does not exist.

Indeed, let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be an increasing differentiable function. Then
$$f(x)-f(a)=(HK)\int_a^x f'(t)\,dt$$
for all $x$,
where $(HK)\int$ is the [Henstock–Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral#Properties). In particular, $f$ is Henstock–Kurzweil integrable on $[a,b]$.
Therefore and because $f'\ge0$, $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$, and hence
$$f(x)-f(a)=(L)\int_a^x f'(t)\,dt$$
for all $x$,
where $(L)\int$ is the Lebesgue integral.

So, $f$ must be absolutely continuous.

Comment: This is likely the proof "from the book" - as Erdős would say.

Comment: @GHfromMO : This is very kind of you.

Answer (score 11):

No, there is not. This follows by an extended version of Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, which asserts that the derivative of $f(x) = \mu((-\infty, x))$ is infinite almost everywhere with respect to the singular part of $\mu$.

To be specific: Let $\nu$ be the Lebesgue measure and
$$ D_\mu \nu(x) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\nu([x-t, x+t])}{\mu([x-t, x+t])} = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \, . $$
If $\nu(A) = 0$, then, by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem,
$$ 0 = \nu(A) \geqslant \nu_{ac}(A) = \int_A D_\mu \nu(x) \mu(dx) \geqslant 0 $$
(here $\nu_{ac}$ is the absolutely continuous part of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$). If follows that $D_\mu \nu(x) = 0$ almost everywhere on $A$ with respect to $\mu$, that is, $f'(x) = \infty$ almost everywhere on $A$ with respect to $\mu$. But $f'(x)$ is finite everywhere, and thus $A$ has measure $\mu$ zero. We have thus shown that $\nu(A) = 0$ implies $\mu(A) = 0$, as desired.

Here we apply the Lebesgue differentiation theorem in a rather unusual way, to the derivative of the Lebesgue measure with respect to $\mu$. See, for example, Theorems 6.8 and 6.9 in [these CUHK lecture notes](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1617/math5012/Real%20Analysis_Chapter_6.2017.pdf), which claim to follow closely [L.C. Evans and R.F. Gariepy, *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*, CRC Press 1992].

Answer (score 6):

Let me add some thoughts to the already existing fine answers.

**1.** The answer is "no" as follows from Propositions 79 and 92 in [Tao's lecture notes on differentiation theorems](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/). Indeed, let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be an increasing differentiable function. By the quoted propositions, $f'$ is absolutely integrable, and
$$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x f'(t)\,dt,\qquad x\in[a,b].$$
Therefore, by a well-known criterion (cf. #6 of Exercise 87 in the notes), $f$ is absolutely continuous.

**2.** Here is a more conceptual explanation based on Theorems 6.10, 6.11, 7.14, 7.21 in Rudin: Real and complex analysis (1987). Consider the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $df(x)$ associated with $f$, and consider its Lebesgue decomposition as in Theorem 6.10. By Theorem 7.14, the absolutely continuous part is $f'(x)dx$, which by Theorem 7.21 is the whole $df(x)$ (i.e. the singular part is zero). So $df(x)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $dx$, which by Theorem 6.11 means that $f$ is absolutely continuous. See also Theorem 7.18 for a slight variation.